# Pre-2013 collection of short stories involving teleportation and time travel, a noir detective, an artist, and a plague doctor

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, soft-sci-fi, anthology-book, teleportation

Around 2011 or 2013, I read a library book of a collection of short sci-fi stories dealing with teleportation and time travel. I don't know how old the book was. There were maybe 10 or so short stories. I can only remember pieces but I want to find it.

One of the stories was a noir style and had a man who I believe was a PI or detective. Someone was chasing him and he needed to escape. Teleportation travel was available but not often used because each time it took something like 9 minutes from your life. You also needed to put on a new skin suit on the other side. There was a scene where in an active escape from the person chasing him, the man jumps in the teleporter and comes out the other side. He is hiding or in a rush to get the skin suit on. The changing room is described kind of like a coat closet or locker room.

In another story, you could pay money to jump into another person's body for a time. People would rent out their bodies if they held a particular skill. The person in the story wanted to paint a beautiful painting -- I believe it was a portrait -- and she went through a company to rent the body of a skilled artist/painter. It was maybe set in a seaside cottage. There was something about people getting bad headaches if in another person's body for too long. I think she rented him for 3 days maybe. Looking in the mirror and seeing the other person's face looking back. I feel like there was some connection to an Asian woman; not sure.

Another story involved a plague doctor. I don't really remember too much else, except something about a cemetery and the description of putting some kind of menthol or spices in the beak of a mask.

Comment: The story about borrowing the artist's body sounds vaguely familiar, and is one I thought I'd seen on here, but no dice so far.